# Change the text of the columns on Trirand JQGrid webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jqgrid, web-controls

I use the trirand JQGrid webcontrol on my website to manage appearance of the data.
Here is the reference:
http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/webforms/jqgrid/

The problem is I want to localize the name of the columns with multiple languages. I've tried many ways but what I've found just for managing the data, not the columns.
Is there anyone knows on how to change the column text from the code behind ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I already have the answer by posting my question to its forum here: http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=18916&#post18916

And here is the answer:

"The syntax you are using can be used only in HTML (will print the value of the Resource inside the HTML). This is not supported declaratively in an ASP.NET WebForms server-control, such as jqGrid.

The way to do this is with code. For example, in Page_Load, you can locate the column of the grid and change its HeaderText to be equal to the resource, e.g.

```
JQGrid1.Columns.FromDataField("DataFieldName").HeaderText = Resources
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the markup, lookt at the Headertext property of the JQGridColumn.
You also need Resource files, one for each language, we assume the Resource file is named "Resources" here in this example.

```
<trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGrid1" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
            Width="600px" Height="260px" onsearching="JQGrid1_Searching" >
        <Columns>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn 
                DataField="OrderID" 
                Searchable="true"
                SearchToolBarOperation="IsEqualTo"
                DataType="Int"
                HeaderText="<% =Resources.OrderId %>" 
                PrimaryKey="True" 
                Width="50" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn
                DataField="CustomerID" 
                HeaderText="<% =Resources.CustomerID%>"
                DataType="String"
                SearchType="DropDown" 
                SearchControlID="DropDownList1"
                SearchToolBarOperation="IsEqualTo"  />
```

Comment: It does not work unfortunately. It would show literally "<% =Resources.OrderId %>" on the header

Comment: Look here for [serverside inline code expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags)

Maybe it's different when using Resource files..
`<%$ Resources:Resource, Arabic  %>`

Try it out

Comment: "Resource" should be the name of your resource file, i.e. localization.resx -->  `<%$ Resources:localization, Arabic %>`

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, as this has nothing to do with jqGrid.
You can also try to use this expression somewhereelse in your aspx page.
Try to create a static class with column names like this:
` public static class Names
        {
            public const string ColumnID = "ID";
            public const string ColumnName = "Name";
        }`

`<% = Names.ColumnName %>`